# List index out of range error in breaking whiloe loop in python

Tags: python, excel

Hi I am new to python and struggling my way out. Currently ia m doing some appending excel files kind of task and here's my sample code. Getting list out of index error as according to me while loop is not breaking at rhe end of each excel file. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks:

```
import xlrd
import glob
import os
import openpyxl
import csv
from xlrd import open_workbook
from os import listdir
row = {}
basedir = '../files/'
files = listdir('../files')
sheets = [filename for filename in files if filename.endswith("xlsx")]
header_is_written = False

for filename in sheets:

print('Parsing {0}{1}\r'.format(basedir,filename))

worksheet = open_workbook(basedir+filename).sheet_by_index(0)


print (worksheet.cell_value(5,6))
counter = 0
while True:
    row['plan name'] = worksheet.cell_value(1+counter,1).strip()
    row_values = worksheet.row_slice(counter+1,start_colx=0, end_colx=30)

    row['Dealer'] = int(row_values[0].value)
    row['Name'] = str(row_values[1].value)
    row['City'] = str(row_values[2].value)
    row['State'] = str(row_values[3].value)
    row['Zip Code'] = int(row_values[4].value)
    row['Region'] = str(row_values[5].value)
    row['AOM'] = str(row_values[6].value)
    row['FTS Short Name'] = str(row_values[7].value)
    row['Overall Score'] = float(row_values[8].value)
    row['Overall Rank'] = int(row_values[9].value)
    row['Count of Ros'] = int(row_values[10].value)
    row['Count of PTSS Cases'] = int(row_values[11].value)
    row['% of PTSS cases'] = float(row_values[12].value)
    row['Rank of Cases'] = int(row_values[13].value)
    row['% of Not Prepared'] = float(row_values[14].value)
    row['Rank of Not Prepared'] = int(row_values[15].value)
    row['FFVt Pre Qrt'] = float(row_values[16].value)
    row['Rank of FFVt'] = int(row_values[17].value)
    row['CSI Pre Qrt'] = int(row_values[18].value)
    row['Rank of CSI'] = int(row_values[19].value)
    row['FFVC Pre Qrt'] = float(row_values[20].value)
    row['Rank of FFVc'] = int(row_values[21].value)
    row['OnSite'] = str(row_values[22].value)
    row['% of Onsite'] = str(row_values[23].value)
    row['Not Prepared'] = int(row_values[24].value)
    row['Open'] = str(row_values[25].value)
    row['Cost per Vin Pre Qrt'] = float(row_values[26].value)
    row['Damages per Visit Pre Qrt'] = float(row_values[27].value)
    row['Claim Sub time pre Qrt'] = str(row_values[28].value)
    row['Warranty Index Pre Qrt'] = str(row_values[29].value)
    counter += 1
    if row['plan name'] is None:
        break
    with open('table.csv', 'a',newline='') as f:
        w=csv.DictWriter(f, row.keys())
        if header_is_written is False:
            w.writeheader()
            header_is_written = True
        w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should take a quick read over this before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: From taking a quick look, it seems you expect the code to break if row['plan name'] is None, but the code before this will try to access the values inside row[]. So if it is None, you will attempt to read the values before the line to break runs ( hence the index error ). It might also never be None as you seem to be increment the value. When do you expect this to be None if you dont explicitly set it to None after initially setting a value?

Comment: Pardon me for my code snippet!I want my my while loop to break and go to next excel file when it reaches end of the first excel file. So i am verifying it with none.

Comment: Would it not be better to open the file and loop over the contents then and let Python decide when to stop the loop? Instead of creating a never ending while loop and having to figure out when to stop reading?

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Hi @brunodesthuilliers i have attached the link of the traceback [link](https://jpst.it/14gbR)

Answer (score 0):

In place of `while True` use `for`.

```
row['plan name'] = worksheet.cell_value(1 + counter, 1).strip()
row_values = worksheet.row_slice(counter + 1, start_colx=0, end_colx=30)
for values in row_values:
    row['Dealer'] = int(values.value)
    row['Name'] = str(values.value)
    ....
```

because `while True` means to run this loop infinite time.(or until it means `break` keyword) inside while loop 
Read more about [while loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop)

Comment: i have added a break in the while loop for particula condition

Comment: in place of `if row['plan name'] is None` **use** `if not row['plan name']`

Comment: @Shubzumt put this `if not row['plan name']`on next line after `row['plan name'] = worksheet.cell_value(1+counter,1).strip()`

Comment: Sorry buddy, but still the same issue. When i am using for loop its overriding the data

Answer (score 0):

`while True` loop basically means: execute the following code block to infinity, unless a `break` or `sys.exit` statement get you out.

So in your case, you need to terminate after the lines to append the excel are over (exhausted). You have two options: check if there are more lines to append, and if not `break`.

A more suitable approach when writing a file is `for` loops. This kind of a loop terminates when it is exausted.

Also, you should consider **gathering the content of the excel** in one operation, and save it to a variable. Then, once you have it, create iteration and append it to csv.